# In Slint, how do I render a self-drawn image?

Tags: rust

In slint 1.1.1, using Rust 1.71, to show self-drawn images `slint::Image` should be used.

But how do I incorporate that into a .slint file? Which property must be set?
Example:

```
canvas := Image {
   Which property must be set?
}
```

Which property do I have to set to update the canvas image?
What Rust code should I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The .slint code:

```
...
in property <image> canvas_source <=> canvas.source;
...
canvas_rect := Rectangle {
    min-width: 200px;
    canvas := Image { }
}
```

The Rust code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let main_window: MainWindow = MainWindow::new().unwrap();

    let window_clone = main_window.clone_strong();
    main_window.window().set_rendering_notifier(move |state, _graphics_api| {
        process_rendering(state, &window_clone)
    })
        .expect("Couldn't add rendering notifier");

    main_window.run().unwrap();
}


fn process_rendering(state: RenderingState, main_window: &MainWindow) {
    match state {
        RenderingState::BeforeRendering => {
            main_window.set_canvas_source(
                render_image(main_window.window().size().width,
                             main_window.window().size().height)
            );
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}

/**
 See https://docs.rs/slint/latest/slint/struct.Image.html.
This is an only slightly modified version, so that the circle is always
in the windows center, with arbitrary window sizes.
*/
fn render_image(window_width: u32, window_height: u32) -> Image {
    let mut pixel_buffer = SharedPixelBuffer::<Rgba8Pixel>::new(window_width, window_height);
    let width = pixel_buffer.width();
    let height = pixel_buffer.height();
    let pixmap_opt: Option<PixmapMut> = PixmapMut::from_bytes(
        pixel_buffer.make_mut_bytes(), width, height,
    );
    if pixmap_opt.is_none() {
        panic!("Couldn't create pixmap image");
    }
    let mut pixmap = pixmap_opt.unwrap();
    pixmap.fill(tiny_skia::Color::TRANSPARENT);

    let circle = tiny_skia::PathBuilder::from_circle((width / 2) as f32, (height / 2) as f32, 150.).unwrap();

    let mut paint = tiny_skia::Paint::default();
    paint.shader = tiny_skia::LinearGradient::new(
        tiny_skia::Point::from_xy(100.0, 100.0),
        tiny_skia::Point::from_xy(400.0, 400.0),
        vec![
            tiny_skia::GradientStop::new(0.0, tiny_skia::Color::from_rgba8(50, 127, 150, 200)),
            tiny_skia::GradientStop::new(1.0, tiny_skia::Color::from_rgba8(220, 140, 75, 180)),
        ],
        tiny_skia::SpreadMode::Pad,
        tiny_skia::Transform::identity(),
    ).unwrap();

    pixmap.fill_path(&circle, &paint, tiny_skia::FillRule::Winding, Default::default(), None);

    Image::from_rgba8_premultiplied(pixel_buffer)
}
```